# Quicktime component not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, quicktime, embedding

I'm experiencing issues with Quicktime in Firefox. I have tried using manual embedding (by the usage of the object/embed tag combination). Firefox ignores the content and does not play it. Safari does.

I then proceeded to use ac_quicktime.js that is provided by Apple themselves to create the embedding code. But i get the same results.

When i try loading the video directly (by locating my browser to the video file) it is not being played as well. Given the fact that it works under Safari, i assume it is a Firefox issue?

I am running Firefox 8.0 but it is not of much relevance, as i am trying to develop a video component for my CMS and this has to run in all major browsers.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: After further testing, i found that Firefox will play the content every few times i reload the page. I added a random seed as parameter to the filename (src="/media/test.mov?seed=2389724932") and with that it seems to work. So it is a caching issue? But how can i correct that?

Comment: More testing revealed that the random seed does not help. After a bunch of page reloads the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be somehow related to the video format - the problem occured with MOV files, not however with MP4 files. I cannot say i found the reason for FFs behaviour, but at least i found a workaround.

Comment: It is pretty certain that FF has bugs playing MP4 using Quicktime.

Comment: This is already a year old but what matters is the encoding, not the file container. Use something like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to check the actual encoding for both video and audio and match to the QuickTime supported formats [list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3775). (source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3775)